# Can I visit the UK while my UK marriage settlement visa application is pending?

Tags: visas, spouses, repeat-visits

I am a US Citizen and travel to the UK often (usually 1 week trips) to see my girlfriend (now Spouse) and visit our clients in London. Since getting married, we want to live in the UK (intention is for me to find a job there once the visa is approved and I have work authorization). Since I usually go to the UK every month with no visa as a visitor, I will need to make a trip or two while the settlement Visa is pending (I plan on keeping my passport while the visa is pending). Will this be allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure we can really help; you may be more likely to get an answer at our sister site [expatriates.se] which deals with issues arising from long term residence and the like.

Comment: You have to send your passport after getting your biometrics done to Sheffield, UK, so you can be without it for a few months. If you have enough money you can get a 1 working day answer using the priority system in the US.